# Change from "click here to add new content" to the WYSIWYG editor in SP2010

Tags: list, form

Currently, to add content, you have to click on "Click Here to Add Content" but since it's a required field (and I think this is sort of unsightly), I'd like to automatically have a WYSIWYG editor in that section already. Even after you click, the content editor is small and I'd like it larger.
See images below.

[image: Unclicked Content Box]

[image: Clicked Content Box]

What I'm looking to do is something like the following for content (side note: I also would like to add a Browse for Attachments button):

[image: Favored Form]

Any direction would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [blog post](http://pirateeric.sharepointspace.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18) about this a little while back, I resortedto javascript to handle this. This was for 2010:

```
function waitUnitStuffIsLoaded() {setTimeout(function(){refocus()},1000);}

function refocus(){$("input[Title='Title']").focus();}   

SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(waitUnitStuffIsLoaded, "sp.ui.spellcheck.js");
```